# Php, lazy-DI: is it OK to add a closure which lazy creates the object?

Tags: php, dependency-injection

we all know this classic DI example:

```
class Test2
{
}

class Test
{
    private $obj;

    public __constructor (Test2 $obj)
    {
        $this->obj = $obj;
    }

    public function use()
    {
        $this->obj->
    }
}

$test2 = new Test2();
$test = new Test($test2);
```

so far so good, but what if the object to insert doesnt exists right know, and maybe it doesnt even have to? What if `use()` will never be called, in that case instantizing `Test2` was useless. A possible solution is here: http://php-di.org/doc/lazy-injection.html but still a (fake and useless) proxy instance is still exists.

What if I do this:

```
class Test2
{
}

class Test
{
    private $objClosure, $obj;

    public __constructor (Closure $objClosure)
    {
        $this->objClosure = $objClosure;
    }

    public function use()
    {
        if ($this->obj == null)
        {
            $this->obj = $this->objClosure->__invoke();
        }
        $this->obj->
    }
}

$test = new Test(function() { return new Test2(); });
```

this mightbe more complicated (and needs more code) but I found it OK. Anybody else?

Comment: Why do you ask?  I mean, is there a specific use-case you need to solve or just curious?

The question of "is it OK...?": my answer would be, if it works - as in solves your problem - and is maintainable for the next guy or you in 6 months from now, then it's OK :)

Comment: because I wanted to know if somebody ever thought of that, and if somebody can see any pitfall of doing that